# Angular 4 owlslider (owl-carousel) fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, angular, owl-carousel, fixed-width

I'm using owl-carousel Angular plugin, but I cant display images bigger than 194px x 145px on the site. The image dimensions should be like this at all image sizes. I tried to overwrite the image dimensions in CSS, but it didnt change anything even with !important.

Also didnt find anything from documentation about that. 
Is the only option to overwrite the core JS files?

My code:

```
<owl-carousel
    [options]="{items: 5, dots: true, navigation: false}"
    [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of resultDataRental.quickscanResponse.rentalData[rentI].imageBytes; let imgI = index">
      <div class="thumbnail-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'transparent'}"><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{img-source}}" alt="rental-image"></div>
    </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

Comment: Try to use style "background-image" with "background-size". The good alternative could be "ngx-carousel":
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? do you mean that I should add the images as a background-image instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. I wrapper the image inside another div, and gave max-width and max-height dimensions to this div.

```
<owl-carousel
    [options]="{items: 5, dots: true, navigation: false}"
    [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of resultDataRental.quickscanResponse.rentalData[rentI].imageBytes; let imgI = index">
      <div class="thumbnail-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'transparent'}">
          <div style="max-width: 194px; max-height: 145px" class="testwrapper">
              <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{imgsource}}" alt="rental-image">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</owl-carousel>
```